# Attendre : subjonctif ou indicatif ?

Tags: usage, subjonctif, indicatif, français-relâché

D'après ce que je connais, on emploie le subjonctif dans la proposition qui suit le verbe attendre.

> J'attends jusqu'à ce qu'il finisse.

J'ai entendu un étudiant (bac+3) dire:

> J'attends qu'il finit.

Cet emploi, fait-il partie du français relâché ? Est-il possible que j'aie mal entendu et que la phrase ait été

> J'attends qu'il ait fini.

?

Dans ce cas, pourquoi la tournure jusqu'à ce qu(e) a-t-elle disparu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce n'est pas académique mais je ne serais pas excessivement surpris d'entendre quelqu'un, même un étudiant, dire ***J'attend qu'il finit***, en espérant que ce ne soit pas un étudiant en lettres modernes...

Il est aussi tout à fait possible qu'une voyelle peu marquée t'ai échappé et que la phrase ait été prononcée comme ceci :

> *J'attends qu'il ait fini* prononcé [ʒa.tɑ̃.kj(ɛ).fini]

*J'attends jusqu'à ce que* est possible mais pas du tout obligatoire.

La forme *j'attend que* n'est d'ailleurs pas récente :

> Ce que j’attends ? J’attends que les os soient vivants !
> Je suis spectre, et je rêve, et la cendre me couvre,
> Et j’écoute ; et j’attends que le sépulcre s’ouvre.
> J’attends que dans les cœurs il s’élève des voix,
> Que sous les conquérants s’écroulent les pavois,
> Et qu’à l’extrémité du malheur, du désastre,
> De l’ombre et de la honte, on voie un lever d’astre !

> Victor Hugo, *[Actes et Paroles - Depuis l'Exil](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Hugo_-_Actes_et_paroles_-_volume_6.djvu/90)*, 1871-1876

Comment: Thanks! What about ` jusqu'à ce qu(e)` ? Is it not obligatory here (J'attends jusqu'à ce que...)?

Comment: No, *jusqu'à ce que* is not mandatory here. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks again jlliagre. I really appreciate it. A native colleague of mine says that J'attends jusqu'à ce qu'il finisse is not used and the form J'attends qu'il finisse is of usage (based on the easiness of pronunciation).

Comment: Sometimes, *j'attends jusqu'à* slightly changes the meaning: *J'attends la nuit* vs *J'attends jusqu'à la nuit*. In the second form, the person might be waiting for something else too while in the first one, the *nuit* is the main thing that is waited for.

Comment: BTW, the student of the question is an engineering one:-)! J'attends qu'il ait fini. When will one use this turn instead of  J'attends qu'il finisse? [I guess with my questions I could start several posts:-)!).

Comment: The meaning is mostly identical (in theory, one happens before the other) but the main difference is the register. *Qu'il finisse* is more formal than *qu'il ait fini*.

Comment: Tous les jours, j'attends qu'il finit de travailler avant de [etc] [wait for] Par contre: J'attends qu'il finisse à l'heure. [espérer: hope or expect]. Oui ou non?

Comment: @Lambie Les deux sens que tu indiques existent mais le mode n'intervient pas. Lesubjonctif est attendu dans les deux cas. *J'attends qu'il **finit** de travailler* est rare et fortement marqué "parler des banlieues".

Answer (score 1):

Le subjonctif est nécessaire après la locution conjonctive  « jusqu'à ce que ». ([Banque Dépannage](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4238)).

C'est du français en relâchement ; la connexion entre contexte et mode subjonctif tend à  faiblir dans l'esprit du monde moderne français, en même temps que le remplacement par l'indicatif s'averre parfois une réappréciation justifiée de cette connexion.

Le changement de « jusqu'à ce que » en « que » dénote un léger changement de sens. (sans référence, ce que je crois comprendre):

***1/ jusqu'à ce que***        L'attente continuera jusqu'au moment où la condition énoncée est remplie. Le moment est une limite qui n'est pas ressentie comme un but.

***2/ que***                         L'objet de l'attente est ressenti comme ayant pour but la condition remplie.

Cependant, les deux possibilités sont aussi idiomatiques l'une que l'autre  dans certains cas.

- J'attends que le facteur passe pour prendre mon courrier de sa main.
- J'attends jusqu'à ce que le facteur passe pour prendre mon courrier de sa main. (*pas habituel*)
- J'attends jusqu'à ce que le facteur passe, il est alors dix heures et je pars pour les champs.
- J'attends qu'il s'arrête de pleuvoir et je m'en vais. (*Il ne veux pas se mouiller.*)
- J'attends jusqu'à ce qu'il s'arrête de pleuvoir ; s'ils ne sont  pas partis à ce moment-là je les mets dehors. (*pas habituel losqu'on ne veut pas se mouiller*)
- Il attend avec ses crocs plantés dans la gorge de la hyène jusqu'à ce qu'elle soit vidée de son sang et morte. (*L'attente dure jusqu'à ce moment-là , et on comprend que ce moment-là (la mort de la hyène) est le but de l'attente.*)
- Avec ses crocs plantés dans la gorge de la hyène, il attend qu'elle soit vidée de son sang et morte. (*Le but de l'attente est la mort de la hyène.*)